# How can I prevent a form submission from taking me to a different page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've programmed a contact form that sends out an email with the details of the inputs.

On submission,**(action="send_form_email.php")** it takes me to the actual PHP file page. Is there any way to prevent this? I currently use this code below to bring me back to the page where the form is, but this prevents the other script from running that lets the person know that the form was submitted successfully.

```
header("Location: http://cvolden.net/");
```

Below is the code that will not echo out:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('thanks');</script>";
```

This form repeats on several pages on the website. In the end, I want the customer to remain on the current page and for them to be notified that everything was sent correctly.

THanks for help!

Comment: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Use AJAX to submit forms without loading a page.

Comment: The other way to do it, that doesn't rely on client-side coding is to post the form to itself and have some code that only executes when `$_POST` is not empty... run your form-mailer in there. Downside with that is if someone hits refresh though; the POST data will still be there and the whole form will be processed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. Default functionality for forms will redirect to whatever the `action` attribute holds. In order to do what you need, you need to use `AJAX`

easy example with Jquery:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var postdata = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr("action"); //something.php;
    $.post(url, postdata, function(res){
        console.log(res); //your PHP results
        alert('thanks');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set target to iframe it will load on same page.

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" target="my_iframe">
  .........................
</form>


<iframe name="my_iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```